# Execute code in webstorm while debugging

Tags: webstorm

I am using webstorm 7.x and google chrome + the IDE chrome debbuging plugin.

I am able to debug my unit test.

When I have set a break on a certain line of code I would like to open a window where I can execute code.

How can I do this in webstorm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 'Evaluate expression' (Alt+F8) for this.
We plan to make debugger console interactive in the next WebStorm version - please vote for [WEB-1171](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-1171) to be notified on any progress

Comment: Thanks for the new feature, can`t wait for it!